# Firebug won't finish installing on Firefox

Tags: firefox, firebug

I'm using Firefox 3.54 and just upgraded the Firebug add-on to the latest version.

I restarted Firefox but the installation of Firebug wasn't finished properly. In the add-on dialog it says that it will be installed next time I'm restarting - but it won't.

Any idea how to fix this? I have already deactivated all other add-ons but that hasn't helped.

Comment: I had this problem installing Firebug 1.7.3 on Firefox 5 (Windows XP), and deleting the profile worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Delete your profile and try again.

Comment: Or restart your computer if it's Windows. If you delete your profile, make sure you backup your bookmarks.

Answer (score 1):

1. Completely remove Firebug and install the latest version. If it doesn't work -
2. Disable all your other add-ons and install it again.  If still no luck -
3. Delete your profile. Install Firebug first, then all your other add-ons.

If you have to delete your profile, remember to make a backup first. You can try [MozBackUp](http://mozbackup.jasnapaka.com/). It can make complete backups of your profile.